# dhcp3-server and strange DNS/NTP servers

Tags: dns, vmware, dhcp, ntp

I have problem with `dhcp3-server 3.1.1-6+lenny4`. My dhcp-server sends "strange" `IPs` for `DNS` and `NTP` servers in `DHCP ACK` despite configuration which doesn't have those IPs. In `ACK` packet we can see the "strange" addresses like:

```
49.57.50.46 or 49.54.56.46 etc.
```

DHCP server configuration is:

```
deny bootp;
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
# $Id: dhcpd.conf,v 1.1.1.1 2002/05/21 00:07:44 peloy Exp $
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
#ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "Test";

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

log-facility local7;
include "/etc/dhcp3/subnet.list.conf";
```

And `/etc/dhcp3/subnet.list.conf:`

```
authoritative;

option f6option6 code 6 = string;
option f6option42 code 42 = string;
option f6option114 code 114 = string;


shared-network HARPER {


subnet 192.168.13.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.13.20 192.168.13.250;
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;
option broadcast-address 192.168.13.255;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option f6option6 "192.168.0.10,192.168.0.18,192.168.13.3";
option f6option42 "192.168.13.3";
option f6option114 "http://192.168.13.3/config";
option tftp-server-name "http://192.168.13.3/config";

host gxp-5f6c52 {
hardware ethernet 00:0B:82:5F:6C:52;
fixed-address 192.168.13.20;
option routers 192.168.13.1;
}

host gxp-5f6836 {
hardware ethernet 00:0B:82:5F:68:36;
fixed-address 192.168.13.21;
option routers 192.168.13.1;
}

host gxp-63dfb1 {
hardware ethernet 00:0B:82:63:DF:B1;
fixed-address 192.168.13.22;
option routers 192.168.13.1;
}
...
```

The subnet.list.conf file contains fiexed hosts configuration and I limited it for only few here.

Under this link there is cap of DHCP communication:
[DHCP_CAP](http://chwarzno.pl/~kristoff/hohner/dhcpKC.cap)

Server is running under Debian 5 on VMware Host.

Comment: Your DNS is working with `test` as TLD? What do you get for `nslookup 192.168.13.20`?

Comment: I remove my TLD from config file for privacy purpose (but You can still see it in DHCP_CAP ;) ) This DHCP server is for local telephone network, and serve only for SIP phones. The subnet.list.conf file contains fiexed hosts configuration and I limited it for only few here.

nslookup for 192.168.13.20  and 192.168.13.32 (witch is in cap file) is this:

> nslookup 192.168.13.20
?Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find 20.13.168.192.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL

Comment: This `49.57.50.46` (decimal) represents `192.` (string). Make you conclusions.

Comment: Thank You so much. After changing option f6option6 code 6 = string;  to option f6option6 code 6 = array of ip-address;  it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ott-- Solution was changing:

```
f6option6 code 6 = string;
```

to:

```
option f6option6 code 6 = array of ip-address;
```